# Code to find the first accruing Index and Last accruing index in a string

Tags: python

I want to write two functions, one that returns the position of the first accruing index in a string, and a different function that returns the position of the last time that index accrues.
For example:

```
index_first('Cats go meow','g')
```

it would return: 5

```
index_last('Cats go meow','o')
```

it would return: 1

and if it's not in the function it would return -1
How do I do this?

I've written some of the code for the first index but if the index isn't in the string it won't return -1. I've pasted it below.

```py
def index_first(string,str_letter):
  r = 0
  for i in string:
    if i != str_letter:
      r += 1
    elif i == str_letter:
      return r
    else:
      return -1
```

If the input is `'Cats go meow','z'`
I expected that it would say -1, but it doesn't send a message at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def index_first(string,str_letter):
    r = 0
    for i in string:
        if i != str_letter:
            r += 1
        elif i == str_letter:
            return r
    return -1
```

You should not put the -1 in the above indent

```
def index_last(string,str_letter):
    r = 0
    for i in string[::-1]:
        if i != str_letter:
            r += 1
        elif i == str_letter:
            return len(string) - r
    return -1
```

As for the other case, simply reverse the string and do a `len(string) - r`

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed to start at 0 so on index last i had it subtract one at the line ````return len(string) - r ````so I made it ````return len(string) - r - 1````

Answer (score 1):

That `else`-part can be never reached because one of `i == str_letter` and `i != str_letter` is always true. Do instead:

```
def index_first(string,str_letter):
    r = 0
    for i in string:
        if i == str_letter:
            return r
        r += 1
    return -1  # only return -1 once you checked all indexes
```

Btw, that logic can be condensed to:

```
def index_first(string, str_letter):
    return next((i for i, r in enumerate(string) if r == str_letter), -1)
```

Or, a little generic, though:

```
def index_first(string, str_letter):
    return string.find(str_letter)
```

And, for the last index:

```
def index_last(string, str_letter):
    return string.rfind(str_letter)
```